# Using speech recognition for easy access to website functions(menu, options, etc.)

Tags: javascript, pycharm, speech-recognition

So, I'm working on a pretty simple project right now where I need to use speech recognition to access the functions of a website.

I made a simple website with just 6 buttons(menu, options, settings, etc.) and I trained a model to recognize these 6 words. Now I need to link the Pycharm script to the website and because I'm very limited in JavaScript I'm stuck at this step.

I created a button that works exactly like an audio recorder, after I press the button it records what I say and then I can download the output manually. But I want it to download automatically and then send the recording as an input to my script.

If anyone has any ideas on how to do it or if you think that I approached it the wrong way please tell me.

Thank you!

Comment: If the goal for the audio is to go via a script on your page, to a download, back into your script, why not use the mediastream (or however you are recording audio) directly in your script?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.